# IntelliJ IDEA Structural Replace

Tags: intellij-idea

Hopefully this is an easy one. I'm trying to convert bad coding standards to javadoc format.

I want to convert this line:

* Created by John.Smith on Jun 13, 2006 at 1:24:54 PM

To:

* @author John Smith

Any help?

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest a plain regular expression find/replace:

Find: `Created by (.*?) on .*$`

Replace: `@author $1`